# The headquarters has different <p> tag and it's name is in another <p> tag and it is changing how can i get all headquarters names correctly?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I need help in correctly scrap the headquarters data from all the links in the http://www.cincinnati.com/story/money/2016/11/26/see-which-companies-16-deloitte-100/94441104/' website

class ProjectSpider(scrapy.Spider):

```
    name = "cin100"
    allowed_domains = ['cincinnati.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.cincinnati.com/story/money/2016/11/26/see-which-companies-16-deloitte-100/94441104/']

    def parse(self, response):

        # get selector for all 100 companies
        sel_companies = response.xpath('//p[contains(.,"Here are the companies")]/following-sibling::p/a')

        # create request for every single company detail page from href
        for sel_companie in sel_companies:
            href = sel_companie.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
            url = response.urljoin(href)
            request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_company_detail)
            yield request

    def parse_company_detail(self, response):           

        # On detail page create item
        item = ProjectItem()
        # get detail information with specific XPath statements
        # e.g. title is the first paragraph
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[1]//text()').extract_first().rsplit('-')[1]
        # e.g. family owned has a label we can select
        item['owned'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"Family owned")]/text()').extract_first()  
    item['Revenue2014'] ='$'+response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"2014")]/text()').extract_first().rsplit('$')[1]
    item['Revenue2015'] ='$'+response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"$")]/text()').extract_first().rsplit('$')[1]
        item['Website'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p/a[contains(.,"com")]/text()').extract_first()
    item['Rank'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"rank")]/text()').extract_first()
    item['Employees'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"Employ")]/text()').extract_first()
    item['headquarters'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[10]//text()').extract()
    item['FoundedYear'] = response.xpath('//div[@role="main"]/p[contains(.,"founded")]/text()').extract()
        # Finally: yield the item
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

While the headquarter has a preceding header labeled "Headquarter" I would take this as anchor and select the content of next following `<p>` tag like so:

```
//p[contains(.,"Headquarters")]/following-sibling::p[1]
```

Maybe you want to have a look at this [XPath Tutorial](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html) to get a better understanding of the commands (and find a better solution).